# PCIe Network Card through USB-C

Tags: usb, pcie

The razer blade stealth supports connecting 16x PCIe graphics card through the USB-C port with external graphics card bays such as the razer core. I'm looking for a PCIe bay (through the usb-c port) so that I can plug in a network interface card, to give my laptop a high-speed connection to a NAS. Does such a thing exist? It would only need to have 4 lanes, would not need to have the power cables necessary for a desktop graphics card, and would be cheaper than the razer core ($500).

Comment: AFAIK, the razer core is the only external PCIe dock right now. If you need 10Gbps, then you'll have to wait a bit longer for other vendors and if you don't there are alreay 1Gbps docks for USB-C (IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

While I know of no **USB-C** PCIe expansion-chassises¹, there are several [Thunderbolt 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)) options. In addition to the mentioned [Razer Core](https://www.razerzone.com/store/razer-core)² ($US 500, 1×PCIe x16, 500W PSU), I looked into these two products when building my Macbook Pro Thunderbolt 3 eGPU solution:

- The [AKiTiO Node](https://www.akitio.com/expansion/node): $US 300, 1×PCIe x16, 400W PSU
- The [Sonnet Echo Express](http://www.sonnettech.com/product/echoexpressseltb3.html): $US 270, 1×PCIe x8, no additional PSU

(There's also a huge number of Thunderbolt 2 PCIe expansion-chassis products, but those are almost certainly irrelevant to your needs.)

Of crucial note when researching this, be aware that the only differences in the above boxes are the *length of the connectable card*, and the *bus-power* provided by the PCIe slot. Although some may advertise “PCIe x16” slots, the Thunderbolt protocol limits the PCIe connection to x4 data-lanes, thus reducing every available expansion-chassis to approximately the same specifications, when it comes to the speed of the connection. (That said, every single one should easily support even a 10GigE networking card.) The only material differences are the cost, the size of the box, and the included PSU.

---

> 1. Having a ‘USB-C PCIe expansion chassis’ would imply a different, non-Thunderbolt proprietary protocol wrapping the PCIe communication into a USB-C ‘Alternate Mode’, which I can't see anybody bothering to do when Thunderbolt 3 exists; so the question as-asked is unanswerable.
> 2. I can also personally vouch for the Razer Core, as I love mine; and it comes very close to maxing out the performance of the absolute *beast* of a video-card I use in it.